# I cant get my php mailer to send a mail using post data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, email

i am having some trouble with phpmailer and ajax. Im quite new to ajax and dont fully understand it yet so this might have a quite obvious fix but here we go.

So when i just put my php mailer script in a page and visit it with set values i can send the mail. but whenever i try to send my form data to the script something doesnt work.

***This is my jquery***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".contact-form").on("submit",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

        function validateEmail($email) {
            var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
            return emailReg.test( $email );
        }
    

        var valid = true;   
        
        if(!$("#name").val()) {
            $("#userEmail").css('border','2px solid #FFFFDF');
            valid = false;
        }
        if( !validateEmail($(' #email').val())) { 
            valid = false
        }
        if(!$("#subject").val()) {
            $("#subject").css('border','2px solid #FFFFDF');
            valid = false;
        }
        if(!$("#message").val()) {
            $("#message").css('border','2px solid #FFFFDF');
            valid = false;
        }
        
    
    //send data to php file
    
        
        var isValid;    
        isValid = valid

        if(isValid) {
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var subject = $("#subject").val();
            var message = $("#message").val();
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "includes/sendmail.inc.php",
                type : "POST",
                data:{name:name,email:email,subject:subject,message:message},
                success:function(data){
                $(".err_msg").text("Send!");
                $(".err_msg").css('background-color', 'green')
                $(".err_msg").show()
                },
                error:function (){}
            });
        } else {
             $(".err_msg").text("Oops! check your input.");
             $(".err_msg").css('background-color', 'red')
             $(".err_msg").show()
            }
    });
});
```

***This is my php***

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
   

    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'mail.example@example.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'example@example.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'example123';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587 ;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom( $email , $name);
    $mail->addAddress('example@example.com', 'John Doe');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo($email , $name);
    


    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $message;


    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

so this is what i have so far i hope you guys can figure out what i did wrong because i have been stuck on this for about two days now.

greetz Floris

Comment: Please share any errors you're getting.

Comment: im not getting any errors. it succeeds, edits the text to Send! so it should have worked but it somehow doesnt work

edit: it executes this part $(".err_msg").text("Send!");
                $(".err_msg").css('background-color', 'green')
                $(".err_msg").show()

Comment: `' #email'` looks like a typo with the space at the start. Remove the space. That could be causing your validation to fail if it can't select the right element. Always double check your work carefully.

Comment: Your XHR callback does not distinguish between success and failure. How do you know "it succeeds"? Try adding some logging in the PHP, and what does `data` tell you in the XHR callback?

Comment: @ADyson, the callback is run, so `isValid` will not have been false. Besides, leading spaces _are allowed_ in a jQuery id selector.

Comment: 'b>Warning</b>:  require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>D:\webProjects\example.com\includes\sendmail.inc.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in <b>D:\webProjects\example.com\includes\sendmail.inc.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
'  ah so i got this this error from console logging data so i guess my path is not right ?

Comment: Did you even install PHPMailer?

Answer (score 0):

yes i figured it out guys thanks ! so what went wrong is that for some reason it wouldnt send because the FROM email adress was a gmail account and i am using my own domain smtp that was causing it appearantly

Comment: Judging from that last error you commented on your question, this seems highly unlikely to have been the sole cause. Good to know you got it working though.

Comment: oh no you are right. I also used the wrong path for the vendor folder. I forgot to add a ../ i forgot to mention that in my answer haha my bad.